# Proof the statements

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Proof the statements below
>
> i)If $P(A)=0$ and $B$ is any event, then $A$ and $B$ are independents
>
> ii)If $P(A)=1$ and $B$ is any event, then $A$ and $B$ are independents
>
> iii)The events $D$ and $D^c$ are independents if only if $P(D)=0$ or
>   $P(D)=1$
>
> iv)Let $E$ any event, fine one condition for which $B$ is independent
>   of himself

What I tried was

i) Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are not independents, then $$P(A\cap B)\neq P(A)P(B)\Leftrightarrow P(A\cap B)\neq 0\Leftrightarrow P(A|B)P(B)\neq 0\Leftrightarrow 0\neq 0$$ 
which is a contradition then If $P(A)=0$ and $B$ is any event, then $A$ and $B$ are independents

ii)Again suppose that $A$ and $B$ are not independent
$$P(A\cap B)\neq P(A)P(B)\Leftrightarrow P(A\cap B)\neq P(B)\Leftrightarrow P(A|B)P(B)\neq P(B)\Leftrightarrow P(A|B)\neq 1$$ $$\Leftrightarrow1\neq 1$$
which is a contradition then If $P(A)=1$ and $B$ is any event, then $A$ and $B$ are independents

iii)Proving first $\Rightarrow$. If $D$ and $D^c$ are independents $$P(D\cap D^c)=P(D)P(D^c)\Leftrightarrow P(D|D^c)P(D^c)=P(D)P(D^c)\Leftrightarrow P(D|D^c)=P(D)$$ $$\Leftrightarrow P(D)=0\vee P(D)=1$$

Proving $\Leftarrow$. Is the same idea of $i)$ and $ii)$

iv)I had never seen it before, but at wikipedia, $$P(A)=P(A\cap A)=P(A)P(A)\Rightarrow P(A)=1 \vee P(A)=0$$
the condition is $P(A)=0 \vee P(A)=1$? How to proof it?

Comment: You have just formed an equation $x^2 - x = 0$ where $x = P(A)$. Solving it, you get 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do them more simply as:

1. $P(AB)\leq P(A)=0$ hence $P(AB)=0$. But $P(A)P(B)=0$ so $P(AB)=P(A)P(B)$ implying $A,B$ are independent.
2. $P(A\cup B)\geq P(A)=1$ hence $P(A\cup B)=1$. So $P(A)+P(B)-P(AB)=1\implies P(B)=P(AB)\implies P(A)P(B)=P(AB)$ so $A,B$ are independent.
3. Suppose $D,D^c$ are independent. Then $P(DD^c)=P(D)P(D^c)\implies 0=P(D)P(D^C)\implies P(D)=0\text{or}1$ Now for the other way, supposing that $P(D)=0\text{or}1$ we have $P(D)P(D^c)=0=P(DD^c)$. So $D$ and $D^c$ are independent.
4. For an event $E$ to be independent of itself, $P(EE)=P(E)P(E)$ i.e. $P(E)=(P(E))^2$. So you get $P(E)=0\text{or}1$.

I have tried to illustrate that you need not use conditional probability. Moreover, you may never know when you cannot apply conditional probability, particularly when you are dealing with null events! Well, you can always extend the definition, but your work will be more cumbersome.